# All links redirect back to homepage?

Tags: joomla, hyperlink

Not sure why this is happening however the first links I've made on the site (web.ear-trumpet.net) are not working. The URL changes, but the site remains on the homepage?

This happens on the menu items as well as the links to articles I've put in a News Gallery (third of the way down). As well as external links such as the 'quick quote' mailto link as you open the page.

Would really, really appreciate some advice as the alternative is to re-install and start again as the developer doesn't seem to have any answers.

Thanks in advance,
Nicol

(ps if you need more info/files I will respond immediately with it. It's a new site so all the files are a standard Joomla 3.1.5 installation and template from Gavick Pro)

Update:

For anyone with same problem. When I switched 'Search engine friendly URLs' to off in Global Config it worked. Worse URLs, but they link properly.

Comment: If you go to your Global Configuration in the Joomla backend and disable SEF URLS, does this fix the issue?

Comment: Yes! It does fix the issue. I had tried changing htacess.txt to .htacess and all sorts but simply doing this has worked! It's a bummer that the URLs are not search engine friendly but I can finally get cracking with it. Appreciate the help!!!

Comment: What host are you using?

Comment: Also, are the SEF URLs with 'index.php' in them or not?

Comment: @David. I'm using Freezone.co.uk. Yes, they had index.php in them.

Comment: Well, I've never worked with them, so can't offer any specifics on the host. However, I have seen some hosts that have an issue with urls like `web.ear-trumpet.net/index.php/menu-alias`. I have had some success by then also enabling the mod_rewrite option in the global config so they look like `web.ear-trumpet.net/menu-alias`. That will work when the other won't. Do make sure you have the htaccess.txt file renamed to .htaccess. If you didn't have the full rewrite enabled in the global config though, the htaccess file was basically useless up to this point.

Comment: @Lodder , you are the man. it did worked for me. Thanks a lot. you saved my life ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check what your site .htaccess file is doing (You will find this in the root installation of Joomla). This could possibly be causing the issue with all page redirects.

Comment: Hi, I tried changing it to .htacess and had guess it was as simple as turning SEF URLs off. Appreciate the help!